# Using jQuery .attr or .prop to set attribute value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attr, prop

I've created a button with an attribute named 'loaded' and initial value of 'no'. Upon clicking the button I'm running some ajax and at the very end of it I'm trying to set the 'loaded' attribute to 'yes' so that the ajax is not run again if the user clicks on the button more than once.

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PDW35/2/

Clicking the button does not change loaded to 'yes'.
However, if you do an alert right after the .attr call like this:

```
alert($(this).attr('loaded'));
```

The alert box does contain 'yes' which doesn't help because once the user clicks, the same code above puts up a 'no' alert box on the screen.

It all behaves the same way if I use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. Am I missing a point here or `.prop()` and `.attr()` just don't work with custom attributes?

EDIT:
Updated jsfiddle using ajax based on the comments below: http://jsfiddle.net/PDW35/5/

Comment: Are you viewing the original source code by any chance when checking the `loaded` attribute? Because it works in that fiddle for me in Chrome

Comment: Everytime I click button for the second time and so on - it alerts `yes`. The attribute is set properly. But try to use allowed attributes starting with `data-` and use jQuery function `data()` for working with them.

Comment: If you're making up your own attribute, prefix it with `data-`. Also, attribute names cannot contain underscores.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome and it doesn't work for me, neither in the jsfiddle nor in the testing environment that I'm using.

Comment: @mmvsbg: How are you testing this?

Comment: working properly How u check?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make the button disabled if you don't want it executed more than once? (or) are you saying that you are doing some other action on button click and don't want only the AJAX call part? (Note: It works for me also in Chrome)

Comment: Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDW35/5/
I'm loading stuff with the ajax (needs to happen only once) but upon clicking the button I'm also doing some .slideToggles which need to happen every time.
In that example I'm seeing the alert box with 'yes' in it every time when I should be seeing it only once after the first click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not exactly sure of the reason why the original code isn't working, but the `$this` seems to be the cause for some reason. Try the below and it seems to work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/PDW35/7/) is here.

I will try to update the answer with the reason as soon as I find it.

```
var loaded = $(".preview-button").attr('data-loaded');
if (loaded === "no") {
    $.ajax({
        success: function (result) {
            $(".preview-button").attr('data-loaded', 'yes');
            alert($(".preview-button").attr('data-loaded'));
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("data loaded");
}
```

Refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595266/ajax-this-not-working) and this seems to be the reason why the `$this` doesnt seem to work from inside the AJAX call.

Comment: That is interesting, you are right!!!
Works now, if I find the reason why $this fails I'll post here as well!

Comment: I think that $(this) is just not defined (or more likely predefined) inside of the .ajax success function. Take a look at the following JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDW35/8/
The first alert box displays the class of the button, the second one just says 'undefined'.

Comment: @mmvsbg no mate, check the update I made to the answer. within the Ajax call $this refers to the call and not your button that fired the event. this is the reason why the first alert (outside the ajax) works and the other (inside) doesnt.

Comment: yes, I just saw that part of the answer now. Thank you very much, helped a ton!

Answer (score 2):

reading the question ..

> so that the ajax is not ran again if the user clicks on the button more than once.

i think you need [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), it allows the event to run just once.. no need of changing the attributes and properties

example

```
 $(".preview-button").one('click',function(){
//your ajax stuff   
    alert('clicked!!!!');
 });
```

Comment: That's a good tip, however, one of the other things that I do upon a click on the button is to .slideToggle a div which needs to happen more than once. I only want to load the ajax once (which goes inside of the div that gets to slide up and down).

Answer (score 0):

You can set property for your `click` (or `submit`) function:

```
$( ".preview-button" ).click( function() {
    this.ajaxCompleted = this.ajaxCompleted || false;

    if ( !this.ajaxCompleted ) {
        // run your request and set this.ajaxCompleted to true in a callback;
    }

    // do other stuff
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following code: once you clicked data is loaded, second time click will alert that data is loaded already.

```
$(".preview-button").click(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('button_id');
var loaded = $(this).attr('loaded');
    if(loaded == "no"){        
        $(this).attr('loaded', 'yes');
   }else{
        alert("Data is loaded");     
   }
});
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PDW35/4/

Answer (score 0):

just change the click function with 'on' like this example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function () {
    let myelem_attr= $(this).attr('data-my-attr');
}
```